# Jump from tag-to-tag in xml?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, filetype-xml

I'm using [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) which says that it can work in `xml` files but I can't seem to navigate between tags.

Say I have this structure:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>slides</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/lib.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

How do I jump forwards to the next tag? E.g., with my cursor on the `1` in the version tag how can I move to the second `s` in the next line? (The first `s` of `system`.)

I already tried `<C-y> n` which is the "move to next edit point" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: so you don't want to jump to the next tag, but to the next tag content?

Answer (score 0):

record the following to a macro

```
/\(<\/[^<]*>\n*\s*<[^<]*>\)\@<=.^M:noh
```

and you can type "n" to go to the second tag ahead, and so on.

`/` start search

`\(` start pattern (`\` is to escape the `(`)

`<` <

`\/` / (`\` is for escaping)

`[^<]*` zero or more of any characters except <  (`[^<]` not < `*` zero or more)

`>` >

`\n*` zero or more newlines

`\s*` zero or more spaces

`<` <

`[^<]*` zero or more of any characters except <

`>` >

`\)` end pattern

`\@<=.` any character (`.`) that comes after the previous  pattern (`\` is for escaping)

Comment: This answer would be strongly improved by an explanation of the pattern.